# How to fix "MidiOutWinMM::openPort: error creating Windows MM MIDI output port."

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, midi

I'm trying to write a program that reads the midi incoming with a library called mido and rtmidi, and whenever I try to open a port it gives me the following message: 
**MidiOutWinMM::openPort: error creating Windows MM MIDI output port.**

I have looked into others that deal with the same problem, but anybody seems to know what to do when you are dealing with this in Windows.

The code that I made is just this:

```
import rtmidi

ports = mido.get_output_names()
print(ports)

port = mido.open_output('mio 1')
```

I expected to work properly but it gives me this error. When I use the rtmidi library happens the same.

Comment: What is the output of `print(ports)`? What is "mio 1"?

Comment: Is this a virtual port? If so, I don't think RtMidi supports virtual ports on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You have another application using the midi device. Close it and the error should be resolved